# PhoneGap App not running in Android Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, android-emulator

I am trying to build/run the PhoneGap 2.0 sample application (\Phonegap 2.0\lib\android\example). I have exported the app into .apk file and installed on mobile. This is WORKING on the actual mobile device but NOT in the Android Emulator. I just cannot see the App Icon so as to start the App. I have looked in the home screen and the App section. I have tried stuff like locking and unlocking the emulator but nothing works.

I have created an Eclipse Workspace on D:\Eclipse 3.7.2 and Created an Android Project form Existing Code through Eclipse from the \Phonegap 2.0\lib\android\example folder.

1. Windows 7 64 Bit
2. JAVA SDK - jdk-7u5-windows-i586.exe (32Bit). Installation looks like this:

   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05
   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\
   - I had to rename the java.exe in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\ folder for Android SDK to find the java.exe in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05 folder. I had to do it even though I had set an Environment Variable called JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\java.exe
3. Android SDK - android-sdk_r20.0.1-windows which is installed on the machine (not extracted via zip file).
4. Installed the following through the Android SDK Manager:

   - Tools

     - Android SDK Tools
     - Android SDK Platform Tools
   - Android 4.0.3 (API 15)

     - Documentation for Android SDK
     - SDK Platform
     - Samples for SDK
     - ARM EABI v7a System Image
     - Google APIs
     - Source for Android SDK
   - Extras

     - Android Support Library
     - Google USB Drivers
5. Created AVD through the Android Virtual Device Manager with the following properties:

   - Target - Android 4.0.3 - API Level 15
   - CPU/ABI - ARM (armeabi-v7a)
   - SD Card Size - 128 MB
   - Build-in - WVGA800
6. Eclipse IDE - Eclipse Indigo Classic 3.7.2 (eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32).zip
7. Eclipse ADT Plugin 20.0.2
8. PhoneGap 2.0.0.zip

I was required to the run the application twice. First time it gave me an error. The next time it was running and shows the emulator.

Log shows:

```
[2012-08-08 19:26:10 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] ------------------------------
[2012-08-08 19:26:10 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] Android Launch!
[2012-08-08 19:26:10 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2012-08-08 19:26:10 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2012-08-08 19:26:10 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
[2012-08-08 19:26:25 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] ------------------------------
[2012-08-08 19:26:25 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] Android Launch!
[2012-08-08 19:26:25 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-08 19:26:25 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] Performing org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample activity launch
[2012-08-08 19:26:25 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MyAVD4.0.3'
[2012-08-08 19:26:25 - org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MyAVD4.0.3'
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that adb is correctly located.The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/

If you don't see this directory in your SDK, launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the android tool) and install "Android SDK Platform-tools".
Follow [this](http://www.mycodeland.com/?p=159) tutorial.

Comment: furqi, thanks for the reply. I followed the tutorial mentioned in the link. I have changes the path to C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk in eclipse (Windows > Prefrence > Android > SDK Location). Now the program is running without any errors. But I still do not see the App Icon anywhere in the emulator. Is there a specific place to look for. It's not on the home screen or on the App Screen.

Comment: I followed this http://gingerbreaddesign.co.uk/todd/2010/10/29/android-emulator-not-installing-apps-a-solution/ and now my App is displayed in the emulator. So now this is a complete solution for any one who wants to gets the first app on PhoneGap up and running.